# System.Speech.Synthesis installing alternate language voices

Tags: .net-3.5, text-to-speech, sapi

The .net framework 3.5 (or vista) provides me with an English voice (David I think) to use with the Speech.Synthesis api. I need a french voice to use with a french dictation practice app I am building for my kids to use to improve their french spelling. The api allows me to change culture when creating a voice, but the default English voice cannot pronounce the french words correctly.

I have been unable to find any way to download a french voice from Microsoft. Is this possible? I did download a Demo commercial voice from Cepstral, but it is crippled in a way that makes it unusable (even for testing). I did not want to buy anything as this exercise is just for fun.

I had hoped alternative language voices might be easily had without resort to the commercial professional voices. Any free alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no free French SAPI 5 compatible voices.  There is a French SAPI 4 compatible voice available from [Microsoft](http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/agent2/lhttsfrf.exe) (licensed from L&H), but it won't work with the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

I never try but I found this: http://espeak.sourceforge.net/

Hope it'll help